# How do I send an OTP to a phone using firebase JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have watched a lot of tutorials but just cant seem to make it work. My phone simply does not receive any OTP from firebase. Other users have faced this problem, but not with JavaScript.

Here is the code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();

var verificationId;

function sendVerificationCode() {
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, window.recaptchaVerifier)
    .then((confirmationResult) => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      verificationId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
      alert("Verification code sent to the phone number.");
      document.getElementById("signInBtn").disabled = false;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error sending verification code:", error);
    });
}

function signInWithPhoneNumber() {
  var verificationCode = getElementById("verificationCode").value;

  var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    verificationId,
    verificationCode
  );

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      var user = userCredential.user;
      document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML =
        "Signed in as: " + user.phoneNumber;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
    });
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Login</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.14.1-0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="phoneSignInForm">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required><br>

        <!-- <div id="recaptcha-container"></div> -->
    
        <button type="button" onclick="sendVerificationCode()">Send Verification Code</button><br>
    
        <label for="verificationCode">Verification Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="verificationCode" name="verificationCode" required><br>
    
        <button type="button" id="signInBtn" onclick="signInWithPhoneNumber()" disabled>Sign In</button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I am not even getting the "Verification code sent to phone number" alert.

This is the console message I received:

```
Uncaught 
w i
a: null
code: "auth/argument-error"
message: "signInWithPhoneNumber failed: Second argument \"applicationVerifier\" must be an implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier."
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

Please tell me where the problem is and how to solve it.

Edit: The answer linked to this question doesn't really explain anything and I still don't understand what is making my code fail.